# How can I determine the voltage requirements of an appliance?

Tags: electrical, voltage

I am moving from the USA to Japan and I really want to take my espresso machine with me. Japan runs on a lower voltage (Japan's voltage is 100 V and the frequency is 50-60 Hz). I have attached a screenshot of the electrical information for my espresso machine but there are two lines. I am not sure which one I should look at to determine what voltage and frequency my machine runs at, and if I will need a voltage converter or not. I also don't know if using a voltage converter will damage my machine at all. Please help. I just want to keep my sanity by making my morning latte every day :')

[image: Espresso Machine Electrical Data]

Comment: Make/model of the machine?

Comment: It seems the label should read 1280W 12**A**, aside from all that labels like this are often conflict with themselves, using Ohms law 12A producing 1280W would be accomplished at 106.7V, so something is a bit, well, random. What is probable is most of the power used is resistive, and reduction to 100V across an approximately 11 Ohm resistive device will produce only about 900W, so something is going to be different, expect cooler, slower, and possibly different tasting coffee.  Make/model could provide some clarity.

Comment: Generally a lot less fuss to buy a Japanese-market espresso machine in Japan, all things considered, rather than fooling around with importing one that's not quite right for the local electric supply and will always be 10% undervoltage at best. DWYL but this is a not-very-sensible hill to die on.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I don't think it matters. I can't think of a way to make a heating element somehow work better at 100v, but I'm not in the business of making heating elements.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease aside from the error on the units for current, it could be continuous power but peak current, e.g. when a pump starts while the heater is running.  Or more likely in this case just rounding to the nearest or next integer as 1280/110=11.63 - that's appropriate precision in the circumstances

Comment: @Nelson it's quite simple, if you are making the heating element for operation on a lower voltage, you make it lower resistance, and it draws more current, thus dissipating more power, because less R is more than offset by I-squared. Presumably things *made for use in Japan* are properly engineered to work on the *available power in Japan.*

Answer (score 5):

You should be fine operating your machine. You probably plug your coffee maker into a regular 120 volt kitchen outlet in the USA which would be the first line of your electrical data. The coffee maker will work fine with Japan's 100 volt service. They use outlets similar to the USA,two prong and three prong. If your appliance is three prong and you move to an area that uses two prong, you'll need an adapter. If your appliance has a two prong, you're good to go with either outlet.

Comment: Electric heating elements will be significantly slower on 100V vs. 120V.

Comment: But then so would every other 100v heating element. It's not like you can create a heating element to be hotter using less voltage... because if you can, they would've done it already. I honestly don't think buying a local one will make a difference because there's no good reason to think the problem is solved. It's a heating element, not a motor.

Comment: @Nelson - What on earth are you wittering on about? You *design* a heating element to dissipate the required power at the specified voltage. A 100V element that dissipates the same power as a 120V element will simply draw more current to do so. I suggest a little research on ohms law.

Comment: Heater elements are not necessarily ohmic. Some are intentionally non-linear exactly to deal with situations like this.

Comment: @fraxinus heater elements in small kitchen appliances are always ohmic. At least I haven't seen a kettle with a kW-rated infrared emitter yet. You are probably referring to the fact that a material's specific resistance changes with temperature.

Comment: Ceramic heater elements are used as well.

Comment: @fraxinus even if not ohmic, that's not relevant. The suggestion that a 100V heater is a 100V heater, and you can't get "any hotter" without more voltage suggests someone hasn't got a clue how things work, and really shouldn't be commenting on issues concerning electricity.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that the manual is printed for multiple models of machines (as a cost saving measure) and it will list all variations in it. So you will need to double check which of those listings apply to the device you have. Check the labeling on the machine itself that should have the electrical specs as well.

Assuming those listing are valid the model you have then the espresso machine has been engineered to work with both voltage ranges and has a power rating for both.

In other words if you plug it into a 110 V outlet it will detect that and draw the 1280W from the wall correctly (and it will draw 12Amps of current doing so)

If on the other hand you plug it into a 220 V outlet will will detect that and draw the same power but will only need half the current.

Comment: That data panel doesn't preclude the possibility that there is a voltage switch on the back.

Answer (score 1):

A simple heating appliances will usually work on lower voltage, just slower. Motors are more questionable, and for electronics it depends on how cheap the manufacturer was when designing the power supply.

US 120VAC sometimes runs low; I know of one old building where it dropped to 90V on a regular basis. So I would guess that your device will *probably* run fine on 100V... But the manufacturer is saying "if it doesn't, or doesn't work well, don't blame us."

You may be able to find a 100VAC to 120VAC autotransformer, or a fancier converter, with adequate current rating in a travel supply catalog. That would be the easiest way to guarantee your espresso machine will work.

Just to ask the stupid question: Have you checked that espresso-grind coffee will be available where you are, or are you prepared to grind your own?

Comment: You are still using a coffee machine which requires pre-ground coffee?

Comment: I use everything from ground-as-needed and french press... to instant. Others are pickier. I don't do espresso for myself; I have little sense of how it's prep differs from other varieties except that I _think_ a fine grind is called for. Since the querant didn't ask about powering a grinder, I wasn't willing to make assumptions but thought someone should sanity-check whether they had accounted for the complete infrastructure.